# Mysql, Complex Where clause slows down query

Tags: php, mysql, performance, latitude-longitude

I have a map tables which is structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `map` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `occupied` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `terrain` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `get_map_w_radius` (`x`,`y`,`id`,`terrain`,`occupied`,`c_type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

There is 40k records with x and y both from 1 to 200.

And in my script I use it like this:

```
SELECT id, terrain, occupied, c_type FROM map WHERE x >= $x-$radius AND x <= $x+$radius AND y >= $y-$radius AND y <= $y+$radius LIMIT 30
```

For example $x is 15 and y is 95 and radius is 5.
When I profile the query, sending data is 0.000496 milliseconds, but without covering index (only x and y instead) it runs faster, even though in theory it should be other way around? 
With covering index, when I do a select query with simple where clause using x and y only one time:

```
SELECT id, terrain, c_type, occupied FROM map WHERE x >= $x And y <= $y limit 30;
```

It's executes much faster, sending data only in 0.000059.
Is there something I am missing or misunderstanding? Maybe it's supposed to be like this?

Comment: 4 comparisons > 2 comparisons ?

Comment: Yeah, but this looks too much. So, maybe there is something to improve?

Comment: Wait you're asking why the query runs faster if you use an index with 2 columns instead of an index with 6 columns?

Comment: get_map_w_radius key has x and y already, right?

Comment: mysql probably isn't using the index because you aren't filtering on those other 4 columns

Comment: No, if I run simple where it is much faster than complex where, but also complex where with get_map_w_radius key is slower than just a key with only two columns x and y.

Comment: @bassxzero What do you mean? The way I understand it works is what mysql first uses two columns from get_map_w_radius key, x and y for where clause. And when it uses others if I specify in SELECT same order as rest of columns in get_map_w_key.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 1):

For a mere 40K rows, suggest adding

```
INDEX(x),
INDEX(y)
```

That way, the Optimizer can look at the `BETWEENs` and pick the one thw might work better and shrink the work *some*.

Further optimizations are tricky.  They are discussed repeatedly in Questions tagged [latitude-longitude].

(Terminology quibble)  "Radius" implies a 2D "distance".  What you have is a "bounding box".

Without `ORDER BY`, the query will return any `30` rows, not necessarily the closest 30.  If you are satisfied with that, fine, since it is faster.

"Covering index" vs `INDEX(x)` -- I have a rule:  Don't create an index of more than 5 columns.  There is nothing really wrong with doing so, it gets gets bulky.  My suggestion of also having `INDEX(y)` is based on the assumption that `y` is sometimes a better filter.

Beware of the Query Cache -- If it is turned on, your 'faster' runs may be due to that.  Run your timings with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to get honest comparisons.

Is your 6-col index UNIQUE?  If so, make it the PK, and totally get rid of `id`.

If `x` and `y` are always 0..200, then make them `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (range of 0..255, and 1 byte instead of 4).

All flavors of 'range' (`BETWEEN`, `<=` - 2-sided or 1-sided) are performed the same.  So any performance differences are artifacts of other things...

1. drill down the BTree to the starting value (which could be the beginning of the table)
2. scan forward
3. stop if `LIMIT` reached *and there is no `ORDER BY`*
4. stop at the ending value (or end of table)